# Automatically scroll to bottom of multiline TextInput while appending text

Tags: react-native

I have a really simple component in react-native to display multiple lines of text.

```
<View style={terminalStyle}>
  <ScrollView horizontal={true} indicatorStyle={'white'} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}>
    <TextInput style={textStyle} multiline={true} textAlignVertical={'top'} editable={false} value={text} />
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

The text shown can be bigger than both width and height of the TextInput.

I manage to get horizontal scrolling through the ScrollView and vertical scrolling through the TextInput. That works perfectly.

Now, I want to automatically scroll down the TextInput when a new line is added.

How can I do this?

By setting the ScrollView to scroll vertically, I was able to add an event handler to scroll to the end.

But, I lost the feature of being able to scroll horizontally.

Moreover, I was able to scroll up, but not down again ... probably something about who's (ScrollView or InputText) getting the scroll event.